# Appropriate Values for AppFabric DataCacheFactory configuration settings?

Tags: configuration, appfabric

In conversations with the `AppFabric` team at MS Support, I was told that the maximum tested data object size for insert to `AppFabric` caching was 5MB per insert.

Based on that base number, could someone recommend starting values for the rest of the `DataCacheFactory` configuration settings that have numeric and timespan value types?

The ones I'm thinking about are spread throughout the various sub-classes used in configuring the `DataCacheFactory`:

- ChannelOpenTimeout
- MaxConnectionsToServer
- NotificationsPollInterval
- NotificationsMaxQueueLength
- RequestTimeout
- TransportChannelInitializationTimeout
- TransportConnectionBufferSize
- TransportMaxBufferPoolSize
- TransportMaxBufferSize
- TransportMaxOutputDelay
- TransportReceiveTimeout

Comment: Anyone has some resource to tackle this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good place to start for AppFabric config

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790927.aspx

There is also this high level config overview:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677351.aspx

Also, these config values should have default values. Maybe try using those, monitoring the performance and tweaking them accordingly.
Ultimately, even if you configure each of them yourself you'll still need to monitor and reconfigure depending on your application.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Scobal. I have already checked those. The problem with the default values is that my objects are way larger than those, and I tried increasing the max buffer size but the performance dropped significantly.  I was hoping to find some correlation among all configuration values, which I haven't been able to find.I also tried the MS AppFabric Customer Advisory Team blog and I haven't heard anything from them..